# How to add next song and previous song play button in audio player using android studio2.3?

Tags: android

I am developing an app with audio player.I want to add next song play button and previous song play button. Following is my code which is working but in this code i want to add next track play and previous track play button.Help me!!

```
//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
    private static final int STEP_VALUE = 4000;

    private TextView selectedfile = null;
    private SeekBar seekBar = null;
    private MediaPlayer player = null;
    private ImageButton prev = null;
    private ImageButton play = null;
    private ImageButton next = null;
    private MediaCursorAdapter adapter = null;

    private boolean isStarted = true;
    private String currentFile = "";
    private boolean isMovingSeekBar = false;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable updatePositinRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updatePosition();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        selectedfile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selecteditem);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        prev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);

        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
        player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.
                INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (null != cursor) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            adapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            prev.setOnClickListener(OnButtonClick);
            play.setOnClickListener(OnButtonClick);
            next.setOnClickListener(OnButtonClick);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        currentFile = (String) v.getTag();
        startPlay(currentFile);
    }

    private void startPlay(String file) {
        Log.i("Selected: ", file);
        selectedfile.setText(file);
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        player.stop();
        player.reset();

        try {
            player.setDataSource(file);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        seekBar.setMax(player.getDuration());
        play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        updatePosition();
        isStarted = true;
    }

    private void stopPlay() {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositinRunnable);
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        isStarted = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositinRunnable);
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }

    private void updatePosition() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositinRunnable);
        seekBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
        handler.postDelayed(updatePositinRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener OnButtonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.play: {
                    if (player.isPlaying()) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositinRunnable);
                        player.pause();
                        play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                    } else {
                        if (isStarted) {
                            player.start();
                            play.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                            updatePosition();
                        } else {
                            startPlay(currentFile);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case R.id.next: {
                    int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;
                    if (seekto > player.getDuration())
                        seekto = player.getDuration();
                    player.pause();
                    player.seekTo(seekto);
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }

                case R.id.previous: {
                    int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;
                    if (seekto < 0)
                        seekto = 0;
                    player.pause();
                    player.seekTo(seekto);
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            stopPlay();
        }

        ;
    };
    private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged =
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    if (isMovingSeekBar) {
                        player.seekTo(progress);
                        Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener", "OnProgressChanged");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    isMovingSeekBar = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    isMovingSeekBar = false;
                }
            };

}

//MediaCursorAdapter.java

public class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
        super(context, layout, c, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                new int[]{R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration});
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));
        long durationInMS = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

        double durationInMin = ((double) durationInMS / 1000.0) / 60.0;
        durationInMin = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(durationInMin)).
                setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue();
        duration.setText("" + durationInMin);
        view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: check out this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Comment: what exactly is a problem? you don't know how to add the button? How to add a click listener to the button? how to switch the track in the media player?

Comment: i want to add  nextsong play and previous song play methods? I know how to add button and onclick listener.But i do not know methods to call the actions on this buttons.